# Что значит static class

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017

Что означает данная конструкция

```
static class Class {};
```

если конструкция не имеет смысла тогда почему студия компилирует ее.

Comment: Компилятор же поясняет - `warning C4091: 'static ': ignored on left of 'Class' when no variable is declared`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Смысл может появиться, если совместно с определением класса будет определена переменная, то есть код трансформируется в следующий:

```
static class Class {} var;
```

Это будет значит, что создаётся переменная только что определённого класса. То, что Visual Studio разрешает подобную конструкцию, т.е. выдаёт всего лишь предупреждение, а не ошибку компиляции, является особенностью компилятора.

Причём `var` в зависимости от контекста может быть как определением глобальной переменной, доступной только в пределах текущего файла, если это написано на уровне глобального пространства имён. А может быть и объявлением статической переменной объемлющего класса, если написано внутри определения класса:

```
struct X {
    static class Class {} var;
};
```

В таком случае, для использования `var` её ещё нужно будет определить вне `X`:

```
X::Class X::var;
```

Comment: разве?.. А не  Class  X::var???

Comment: @ARHovsepyan сначала задаётся полный тип переменной, это `X::Class`, далее класс, к которому принадлежит переменная, т.е. `X`, ну и после `::` имя переменной `var`. `Class` находится внутри `X`, поэтому для обращения снаружи (а это используется для определения статических членов класса) требуется указать полный тип.

Comment: Да, это моя невнимательность.  Я ошибся

Answer (score 3):

Такая конструкция ничего не значит - она не компилируема в приниципе. С++ испокон веков разрешал спецификаторы класса хранения (`static` в данном случае) только в объявлениях объектов или функций.

> **10.1.1 Storage class specifiers**
>   **4** The static specifier can be applied only to names of variables and functions and to anonymous unions [...]

http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.stc#4

Данная конструкция не объявляет ни объекта, ни функции. Любой С++ компилятор обязан выдать диагностическое сообщение в ответ на такую конструкцию.

Понятия "компилирует" или "не компилирует" в мире С++ не существует. Корректность С++ кода определяется в первую очередь наличием или отсутствием диагностических сообщений компилятора.

В данном случае решение компилятора продолжить компиляцию после выдачи диагностического сообщения, возможно, вызвано наследием языка С, в котором такие бессмысленные спецификаторы класса хранения являются допустимыми (хоть и тоже бессмысленными).